# Filter by SUM() of multiple wheres

Tags: sql-server, group-by, sum, filtering

I need to build a query that returns the order_ID filtering by SUM(function).

Let say I need filter the data below only when the sum of "pen", "pencil" and "eraser" is equal or greater than 15. In other words, i need to exclude "stamp" and "frames". I guess I need to GROUP BY order_ID

```
order_ID |article_ID | QTY |
---------------------------- 
   1     |  pen      | 5   |
   1     | pencil    | 5   |
   1     | eraser    | 5   |
   1     | stamp     | 3   |
   1     | frames    | 3   |
   2     |  pen      | 3   |
   2     | pencil    | 5   |
   2     | eraser    | 5   |
   3     |  pen      | 5   |
   3     | pencil    | 10  |
```

I expect to get only order_ID = 1, because both 2 and 3 are out of my conditions. Can you help me please?

Comment: Why would you not get order_id 3, since it has pen and pencil = 15?

Comment: Same remark as Tab Alleman. Does it mean that there must exist a record for each of "pen", "pencil" and "eraser"?

Answer (score 1):

Post aggregation filtering should do it.

```
SELECT order_id FROM t 
WHERE article_id IN( "pen", "pencil", "eraser" )
 GROUP BY order_id
HAVING SUM(QTY)>=15
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use conditional aggregation as below:

```
Select order_id from #yourorder group by order_id
having sum(case when article_id in ('pen','pencil','eraser') then qty else 0 end) >= 15
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your input , the order_id 1 & 3 will be returned , **NOT** only order_id 1

> only when the sum of "pen", "pencil" and "eraser" is equal or greater
>   than 15

as next demo:-

```
Create table mytable (order_ID  int , article_ID  varchar(20),QTY int)
insert into mytable values
(1,'pen',5),
(1,'pencil',5),
(1,'eraser',5),
(1,'stamp',3),
(1,'frames',3),
(2,'pen',3),
(2,'pencil',5),
(2,'eraser',5),
(3,'pen',5),
(3,'pencil',10)

select order_ID,sum(QTY) SumQty
from mytable
WHERE article_id IN('pen','pencil','eraser' )
group by order_ID  
having sum(QTY) => 15
```

**Output:-**

```
order_ID    SumQty
  1          15
  3          15
```